# Regular expression for just 7 digits and 9 digits

Tags: regex

I was searching for regular expression for just 7 digits and another for just 9 digits, all I found was for [0-7] and [0-9], not exact 7 and 9 digits - no shorter no longer-

How can I find those ?

Comment: Do you want to ensure if a string consists of either 7 or 9 digits? Or do you want to find a series of digit inside a longer string? What if the string contains a series of 10 digits, should it match? If not, what surrounds the 10 digits?

Comment: Hey, if you're looking for a good source to learn and write your own regular expressions, check this out: [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Matching seven digits:

```
^\d{7}$
```

Matching nine digits:

```
^\d{9}$
```

If you want to match either seven or nine digits, use this:

```
^(\d{7}|\d{9})$
```

or just this:

```
^\d{7}(\d{2})?$
```

**Quantifier**: The number in curly braces is what we call the *quantifier*, it determines how many repetitions of the preceding pattern (character or group in parentheses) are matched.

**Beginning** and **end** of a string (or line) are denoted with the caret `^` and dollar sign `$` respectively.

The **pipe character** `|` is used to provide two alternative patterns. It is important to know, that it's precedence is *lowest* (thanks raina for reminding me), i.e. it will either match *everything* to its left or to its right, unless constrained with parentheses.

Comment: @raina77ow Anchors? What do you mean?

Comment: `/\d{7}|\d{9}/.test(12345678)` => true

Comment: @phant0m on your very last example, i wrote it slightly different expecting same result (which is match exactly 7 digits or exactly 9). Say i provided 8 digits, why would this query, `^\d{7}|\d{9}$` , match the first 7?

Answer (score 3):

For 7 digits: `/^\d{7}$/`

For 9 digits: `/^\d{9}$/`

Stackoverflow was down and I had to "learn" the Regex.

Found it here:
[Regular expressions in javascript](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regular-expressions-in-javascript/)

Learning was better :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it clear what you want from your post.  Are you looking for a string of either 7 digits or 9 digits?  Something like: (\d{9}|\d{14})

Answer (score 0):

While I am way late to this thread, I felt that another answer is needed because the only answers included here assume that the numbers you are looking for are the only thing in their line.

However, if your data includes more information on each line and you are wanting to find all the 7 and/or 9 digit numbers, then the following regex would work:

```
(?<!\d)(\d{7}|\d{9})(?!\d)
```

The first section `(?<!\d)` is a negative lookbehind that matches any digit character. Since it is negative, it excludes all results that contain a digit before the potential match.

The second section `(\d{7}|\d{9})` has been explained in other answers, but it looks for repeating digit characters that are repeated either 7 or 9 times.

The last section `(?!\d)` is a negative lookahead that matches any digit character. Like the lookbehind, since this negative, if it finds a digit after the potential match, it excludes it.

While this is an old question, hopefully this solution helps someone who finds this thread with the same problem.